# Twitter API - know if tweet has been sent

Tags: twitter, webintents

Is it possible, using Twitter's Web Intents, to have a link that when clicked :

- Opens a popup to send a tweet containing the link I have chosen (no problem so far, I have tried that and it works)
- Then, once the tweet is sent, calls a js or php script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter's Tweet Web Intent doesn't provide this functionality. You'd have to build a solution using either the REST or Streaming APIs. Even that would only work if the user's Tweets are public, or if they give you read access to their timeline.

Comment: Thanks! How about using twitter-api-php and sending the tweet with a custom form ?

Comment: @Gejii twitter-api-php is a wrapper around the REST API, so you should be able to build what you want with that.